# Custom variant for product

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a marketplace app that user can upload their own products. And the database of choice is Firestore.

Now I am stuck with how should I model the variant object
This is what I want to build
[image]

The variant can be customize by the seller, Colors, Sizes, Types, Specs etc. Maximum variant is 2.

Depends on the variant combo selected it should be able to show different price and stock.

The only way I can come up with is to model the Product and Variant object like this,

```
class Product extends Equatable {
  final String? id;
  final Shop seller;
  final double? price;
  final String title;
  final Map<String, List<Variant>> variants
```

```
class Variant extends Equatable {
  final String? id;
  final String? imageUrl;
  final String name;
  final double? price;
  final int? stock;
  final Map<String, List<Variant>>? subVariants;
```

So in the above case the data will look like this

```
Product(
   variants: [{
      'Colors': Variant(
         name: 'Red',
         subVariants: {
            'Sizes': [Variant(
               name: 'S',
               stock: 100,
               price: 299.9,
               ),
               Variant(
               name: 'M',
               stock: 100,
               price: 299.9,
               ),
            ]}
```

I think it should work but it seems over-complicated and not easy to manage and compare.

Is there any suggestion on how should I implement this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the two variant classes.

One holds the variant name and subvariants, it does not hold price and stock while the other class holds name, stock and price.

So one can be `VariantCategory` which will contain variants and the other will be `Variant`

```dart
class Product {
  final String id;
  final Shop seller;
  final double price;
  final String title;
  final Map<String, List<VariantCategory>> variantCategories;

  Product({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.seller,
    @required this.price,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.variantCategories,
  });
}

class VariantCategory {
  final String name;
  final List<Variant> variants;
  final Map<String, List<VariantCategory>> subCategories;

  VariantCategory({
    @required this.name,
    @required this.variants,
    @required this.subCategories,
  });
}

class Variant {
  final String id;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String name;
  final double price;
  final int stock;

  Variant({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.imageUrl,
    @required this.name,
    @required this.price,
    @required this.stock,
  });
}
```

For a single Category, here's a sample:

```dart
Product one = Product(
    variantCategories: {
      'Colors': [
        VariantCategory(
          name: 'Red',
          variants: [
            Variant(
              id: 'id',
              imageUrl: 'imageUrl',
              name: 'name',
              price: 100,
              stock: 10,
            )
          ],
          subCategories: {},
        ),
      ],
    },
    id: id,
    seller: seller,
    price: price,
    title: title
  );
```

For multiple categories, here's a sample:

```dart
Product multiple = Product(
    variantCategories: {
      'Colors': [
        VariantCategory(name: 'Red', variants: [
          Variant(
            id: 'id',
            imageUrl: 'imageUrl',
            name: 'name',
            price: 100,
            stock: 10,
          ),
          Variant(
            id: 'id',
            imageUrl: 'imageUrl',
            name: 'name',
            price: 100,
            stock: 10,
          )
        ], subCategories: {
          'Size': [
            VariantCategory(name: 'Red', variants: [
              Variant(
                id: 'id',
                imageUrl: 'imageUrl',
                name: 'name',
                price: 100,
                stock: 10,
              ),
              Variant(
                id: 'id',
                imageUrl: 'imageUrl',
                name: 'name',
                price: 100,
                stock: 10,
              )
            ])
          ],
        }),
      ],
    },
  );
```

You can get all variant categories from a product by doing this:

```
product.variantCategories.values.expand((i) => i).toList(); //returns a List<VariantCategory>
```

Comment: Hi Victor, thanks for the answer. And Product => variant will be Map<String, List<VariantCategory>> right?

Comment: What about the case with only 1 type of variant? Lets say there is only color variant

Comment: Sorry Victor, I am confused here, we have Map<String, List<VariantCategory>> for variant, but VariantCategory as you suggest do not have price and stock info

Comment: In that case, you have a single `VariantCategory` which will contain the subvariants that can include price and stock info. The number of variants should not change since we're using `Lists` and `Maps`

Comment: I've updated the code to use `variants` instead of `subvariants` for the `Variant` objects attached to a `VariantCategory`.

Comment: I am sorry, can you please include the example for only one variants too? I am still a little bit confuse here. Thank you so much for you help Victor

Comment: I see what you're saying now. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: Hi Victor, but in this case there will be 3 "name" required.

Comment: for each variant I mean. In ur example it is Color, Red, name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235438/discussion-between-victor-eronmosele-and-ennis).